# Need custom authentication for signal-R and signal-R hub methods in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

This my client code and hub, If I use authorize attribute in above hub, hub is connecting and I debugged it executes the method but message isn't showing in browser. If I remove the authorize attribute, message is showing in browser. I need custom authorization for hub connection and hub method.

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .WithUrl("https://localhost:44364/chathub"
    , options =>
    {
        options.AccessTokenProvider = () => Task.FromResult(token);
    })         
    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
    .Build();
await connection.StartAsync();          
await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", "Hello"); 

//startup configuration

services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = "https://mywebapi.com",
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234567890123456789")),
        ValidAudience = "https://mywebapi.com",
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    };      
});         
services.AddSignalR();

// HUB
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
       await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @viji, I think you need check this official document to learn how to authenticate jwt with signalr:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: Hi@Rena I tried above the link but that hasn't worked for my real time project.